# TPM2 NVM write in EDK2 EFI_DEVICE_ERROR

Tags: tpm, edk2

I am trying to use the functions in Tpm2CommandLib to write data to TPM2 in EDK2. I have defined the index that I am going to write data to, using the DefineSpace function. Whenever I am trying to use the Tpm2NvWrite function, I keep getting EFI_DEVICE_ERROR with a response code 0x1D5. Is there anything to do before Tpm2NvWrite that I don't know or do I use the wrong parameters?

I tried to change the AuthSession parameters but nothing has changed. I changed Offset just to be sure if everything is alright at that side of the code.

```c
EFI_STATUS
EFIAPI
DefineSpaceTPM2(
) 
{
  EFI_STATUS                      Status;
  UINT32                          authSize;
  ORIG_AUTH_AREA                  authArea;
  TPM2_NV_DEFINE_SPACE_COMMAND    CmdBuffer;
  UINT32                          CmdBufferSize;
  TPM2_NV_DEFINESPACE_RESPONSE    RecvBuffer;
  UINT32                          RecvBufferSize;
  ORIG_NV_PUBLIC                  publicInfo;

  // Auth Area
  authArea.sessionHandle = SwapBytes32(TPM_RS_PW);
  authArea.nonceSizeZero = SwapBytes16(0);
  authArea.sessionAttributes.continueSession = 0;
  authArea.sessionAttributes.auditExclusive  = 0;
  authArea.sessionAttributes.auditReset      = 0;
  authArea.sessionAttributes.reserved3_4     = 0;
  authArea.sessionAttributes.decrypt         = 0;
  authArea.sessionAttributes.encrypt         = 0;
  authArea.sessionAttributes.audit           = 0;
  authArea.hmacSizeZero = SwapBytes16(0);
  authSize = sizeof(authArea);

  // publicInfo area
  publicInfo.nvIndex = SwapBytes32(NV_INDEX_FIRST + 0x10);
  publicInfo.nameAlg = SwapBytes16(TPM_ALG_SHA256);
  publicInfo.attributes = SwapBytes32(0x20f500f);
  publicInfo.authPolicySizeZero = SwapBytes16(0);
  publicInfo.dataSize = SwapBytes16(16);
  publicInfo.size = SwapBytes16(sizeof(publicInfo) - sizeof(publicInfo.size));


  // set parameters
  CmdBuffer.Header.tag         = SwapBytes16(TPM_ST_SESSIONS);
  CmdBuffer.Header.commandCode = SwapBytes32(TPM_CC_NV_DefineSpace);
  CmdBuffer.authHandle         = SwapBytes32(TPM_RH_OWNER);
  CmdBuffer.authSize           = SwapBytes32(authSize);
  CmdBuffer.authArea           = authArea;
  CmdBuffer.authSizeZero       = SwapBytes16(0);
  CmdBuffer.publicInfo         = publicInfo;
  CmdBufferSize = sizeof(CmdBuffer.Header) + sizeof(CmdBuffer.authHandle) + sizeof(CmdBuffer.authSize) + 
                  sizeof(CmdBuffer.authArea) + sizeof(CmdBuffer.authSizeZero) + sizeof(CmdBuffer.publicInfo);
  CmdBuffer.Header.paramSize = SwapBytes32(CmdBufferSize);

  // send TPM command
  DEBUG((DEBUG_INFO, "DefineSpaceTPM2 Sending..\n"));
  RecvBufferSize = sizeof(RecvBuffer);
  Status = Tpm2SubmitCommand (CmdBufferSize, (UINT8*)&CmdBuffer, &RecvBufferSize, (UINT8*)&RecvBuffer);
  if (Status != EFI_SUCCESS) {
    DEBUG((DEBUG_INFO, "Code couldn't be submitted\n"));
    return Status;
  }

  UINT32 res = SwapBytes32(RecvBuffer.Header.responseCode);
  if (res != TPM_RC_SUCCESS) {
    DEBUG ((EFI_D_ERROR, "DefineSpaceTPM2 - responseCode - %x\n", res));
  }

  return Status;
}

EFI_STATUS
EFIAPI
WriteToDefinedSpace(
)
{
  EFI_STATUS                Status;
  TPMI_RH_NV_AUTH           AuthHandle;
  TPMS_AUTH_COMMAND         *AuthSession;
  TPM2B_MAX_BUFFER          *InData,
  UINT16                    Offset

  AuthSession = (TPMS_AUTH_COMMAND*) AllocateZeroPool (sizeof(TPMS_AUTH_COMMAND));
  OutData = (TPM2B_MAX_BUFFER *) AllocateZeroPool (sizeof(TPM2B_MAX_BUFFER));
  InData = (TPM2B_MAX_BUFFER *) AllocateZeroPool (sizeof(TPM2B_MAX_BUFFER));


  //MAX_DIGEST_BUFFER is default and the value is 1024
  OutData->size = MAX_DIGEST_BUFFER * sizeof(BYTE);
  InData->size = MAX_DIGEST_BUFFER * sizeof(BYTE);

  Size = 0x2;
  Offset = 0x0;

  InData->buffer[0] = 0xC;
  InData->buffer[1] = 0xC;

  AuthSession->sessionHandle = TPM_RS_PW;
  AuthSession->nonce.size = 0;
  CopyMem (AuthSession->nonce.buffer, NULL, 64 * sizeof(BYTE));
  AuthSession->sessionAttributes.continueSession = 0;
  AuthSession->sessionAttributes.auditExclusive  = 0;
  AuthSession->sessionAttributes.auditReset      = 0;
  AuthSession->sessionAttributes.reserved3_4     = 0;
  AuthSession->sessionAttributes.decrypt         = 0;
  AuthSession->sessionAttributes.encrypt         = 0;
  AuthSession->sessionAttributes.audit           = 0;
  AuthSession->hmac.size = 0;
  CopyMem (AuthSession->hmac.buffer, NULL, 64 * sizeof(BYTE));

  AuthHandle = TPM_RH_OWNER;

  Status = Tpm2NvWrite (AuthHandle, NV_INDEX_FIRST + 0x10, AuthSession, InData, Offset);
  if (Status != EFI_SUCCESS){
    DEBUG((DEBUG_INFO, "Tpm2NvWrite Status at WriteToDefinedSpace Tpm: %r\n", Status));
  }

  return Status;
}
```

Comment: This should be the error TPM_RC_SIZE for parameter 1. Can you post your code?

Comment: Thanks for your answer !! I have edited the post and added the code. What do you mean by parameter 1?

Comment: Parameter 1 of the "low level" call, as defined in the specification (part 3). How much space have you allocated for the NvIndex?

Comment: Hey, @MiSimon. Sorry for my late response. I have added the DefineSpace function that wrote to the post for additional information. I have looked at the specification Part 3 but, I am still not sure what you mean by Parameter 1. I am not sure where to allocate space for NvIndex. Do you mean the DataSize parameter in NvPublic?

Comment: Hey @MiSimon,  I really need help in this subject. I would be greatful if you answer

Comment: You allocate 16 bytes for the NvIndex and want to write 2 bytes, correct? Have you tried to set InData->Size = 2.